# ggplot not installing - tried everything

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang, install.packages

I'm out of options to install `ggplot`. I tried installing from Tools, from the console itself, indicating the cran source, indicating the local dir that the ggplot.gz file appears in. None of them works. I tried installing `devtools` first but same issue with that package too. I still get the error as follows:

```
 install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘withr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
lifecycle  0.2.0  1.0.1             FALSE
rlang      0.4.5  1.0.2              TRUE
scales     1.1.0  1.2.0             FALSE
withr      2.2.0  2.5.0             FALSE
ggplot2    3.3.0  3.3.6             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\asadeghi8\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY96UwM\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’, ‘withr’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 99716 bytes (97 KB)
downloaded 97 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 270188 bytes (263 KB)
downloaded 263 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/withr_2.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 102089 bytes (99 KB)
downloaded 99 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3061989 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing '\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'withr' ...
** package 'withr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'withr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    defer                                   html  
    devices                                 html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/asadeghi8/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIN8vq1/R.INSTALL987c3eca7587/withr/man/devices.Rd:228: file link 'X11' in package 'grDevices' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    makevars_user                           html  
    set_makevars                            html  
    with_                                   html  
    with_collate                            html  
    with_connection                         html  
    with_db_connection                      html  
    with_dir                                html  
    with_envvar                             html  
    with_file                               html  
    with_gctorture2                         html  
    with_language                           html  
    with_libpaths                           html  
    with_locale                             html  
    with_makevars                           html  
    with_options                            html  
    with_package                            html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/asadeghi8/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIN8vq1/R.INSTALL987c3eca7587/withr/man/with_package.Rd:68: file link '.libPaths' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    with_par                                html  
    with_path                               html  
    with_rng_version                        html  
    with_seed                               html  
    with_sink                               html  
    with_temp_libpaths                      html  
    with_tempfile                           html  
    with_timezone                           html  
    withr                                   html  
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5/withr/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5/withr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘withr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing '\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5/scales'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'scales', 'withr' are not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing '\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\asadeghi8\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY96UwM\downloaded_packages’
> library("ggplot")
Error in library("ggplot") : there is no package called ‘ggplot’
```

I tried to update the `rlang` package but it when I install it again, it's the same version. This is how it's installed:

```
> install.packages("rlang")
Installing package into ‘\\corp.bloomberg.com/ny-dfs/Users/asadeghi8/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  0.4.5  1.0.2              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\asadeghi8\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwpTtFm\downloaded_packages
```

Comment: The main error is `namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required`. Make sure you restart R and don't load any packages before you try to install new ones. If you have any code that runs automatically when you start R, like in a `.Rprofile` file, make sure you turn that off. First try to update `rlang` with `install.packages("rlang")`. Make sure that runs successfully before installing `ggplot`.

Comment: The ```rlang``` is there but even when I'm reinstalling it, the version stays the same. @MrFlick

Comment: You're saying that `install.packages("rlang")` runs without error but when you run `library(rlang)` and then `sessionInfo()` afterward, it still shows `rlang 0.4.5` as being installed? What version of R are you running? Is it an old version?

Comment: Exactly. I detached the package and reinstalled it just to cover all the bases but still same version. @MrFlick

Comment: What is your version of R?

Comment: I added the log when installing ```rlang```. It's 3.5.3 (2019-03-11). @MrFlick

Comment: I'm sure how you've been detaching the package, but it's always safest to restart R to make sure the package can be updated. But you are using an old version of R. Unless you have a compelling reason to not do so, I'd recommend updating to at least R 4.1.

Comment: Okay, I'ma try that and see if it works. @MrFlick